# Continuity of differential operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that the functional: $T:C^1_{[0,1]} \to C^0_{[0,1]}$ defined by $Tf = f'$ is continuous, using the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x) - g(x)|$.

I start by taking $f,g$ with $d(f,g) < \delta $ for some $\delta > 0$. Then proceed by:

$$
d(Tf, Tg) = d(f', g') = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x) - g'(x)|
$$

I'm not quite sure how to use the information about the distance between $f,g$ to continue though

Comment: What distance are you using on $C^1$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli the sup metric, same as for $C$

Comment: Then you are trying to prove a false statement.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli oh.. do you have a counter example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$, but it is not true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}T(f_n)=T(0)=0$.

Comment: does this mean that for any metric this is not true? your answer seems to be independent of the choice of metric?

Comment: @dimebucker Not at all. The claims $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'\neq0$ **do** depend upen the metric. For instance, if $d(f,g)=\int_0^1|f-g|$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'=0$.

Comment: So just that I completely understand it, you take $f_n(x)$ and $g(x) = 0$ and show that $d(f_n, g)  = d(f_n, 0) \to 0$ but $ d(Tf_n, T0) \to 1$ when $d = \sup |f-g|$

Comment: @dimebucker Almost. I never claimed that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'=1$. This is not true. The sequence $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is **not** convergent.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, so the limit is infinite, and so there exists a case in which we can bound the $d(f,g)$ but not $d(Tf, Tg)$ and so $T$ is not continuous (under this particular metric)

Comment: @dimebucker No. The limit is **not** infinity. That doesn't even make sense. The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'$ **does not exist**.